# knitr problem after update to R 3.0.0

Tags: errors, r, knitr

I just updated R to 3.0.0. I couldn't compile PDF from my .Rnw file, which I could do with R 2.15. Here is the error I got:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.192 \SweaveOpts
                 {concordance=TRUE}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

It seems related to Sweave. But I was using knitr to weave .Rnw file. Could some one help me fix the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` in your Rnw file. It is invalid and useless to `knitr`.

Update: I have fixed the plot problem in the development version (v1.2.4). See [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) for instructions on installation. It will go to the stable version 1.3 eventually, but perhaps not until a month later.

Comment: Yihui, Thank you so much for your quick response. I removed \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE} from the Rnw file, which was put in my Rnw file by Rstudio when Preference -> Sweave -> "Always enable Rnw concordance (required for syntex)" was checked. I had to uncheck that option. The error is gone. But I still have problem to compile PDF file with some warnings. I will try to figure it out later. [Update 4/13/13]: The problem is knitr generated two figure PDFs for one code chunk. And the first PDF has no page, which causes the following error: !pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ./figure/minim